# For $a<x<b$, given definition of convexity as $\frac{f(x)-f(a)}{x-a}<\frac{f(b)-f(a)}{b-a}$, is $\frac{f(b)-f(x)}{b-x}>\frac{f(b)-f(a)}{b-a}$ true?

Tags: calculus, derivatives

Given the following definition of a convex function $f$

> A function $f$ is convex on an interval if for $a,x$, and $b$ in the
> interval with $a<x<b$ we have
>
> $$\frac{f(x)-f(a)}{x-a}<\frac{f(b)-f(a)}{b-a}\tag{1}$$

The geometric reason for this definition is that the line segment from $(a,f(a))$ to $(b,f(b))$ (blue line segment in picture below) lies above the graph of $f$ (green below). The equations that describe such a situation result in $(1)$.

[image]

$(1)$ says that the slope of a line passing through $(a,f(a))$ and $(x,f(x))$ is smaller than the slope of a line passing through $(a,f(a))$ and $(b,f(b))$, for all $x \in (a,b)$.

It seems like it would also make sense to express this slightly differently: the slope between $(x,f(x))$ and $(b,f(b))$ must be larger than the slope between $(a,f(a))$ and $(b,f(b))$, for all $x \in (a,b)$.

$$\frac{f(b)-f(x)}{b-x}>\frac{f(b)-f(a)}{b-a}$$

Is this true? If so, how does one obtain it from the definition given above?

Comment: Have you tried to expand an inequality (1) and use the fact that a < x < b?

Comment: Multiply both nequalities by the product of the denominators and you will notice they are equivalent.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Straightforward calculation:

\begin{align}
&\frac{f(x)-f(a)}{x-a}<\frac{f(b)-f(a)}{b-a}\\
&\iff f(x)-f(a) < \frac{x-a}{b-a}(f(b)-f(a))\\
&\iff f(x) < f(a)+\frac{x-a}{b-a}(f(b)-f(a))\\ 
&\iff -f(x) > -f(a)-\frac{x-a}{b-a}(f(b)-f(a))\\ 
&\iff f(b)-f(x) > f(b)-f(a)-\frac{x-a}{b-a}(f(b)-f(a)) = (1-\frac{x-a}{b-a})(f(b)-f(a)) = \frac{b-x}{b-a}(f(b)-f(a))\\
&\iff \frac{f(b)-f(x)}{b-x}>\frac{f(b)-f(a)}{b-a}
\end{align}